# XPath select last element if child element has value

Tags: xml, xpath

For example we have next XML file. Some orders have descriptions; some haven't. How I can take last order, that have `DESCRIPTION` element?

```
<ORDERSINFO>
  <ORDER>
    <NUMBER>168756</NUMBER>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
    <NUMBER>16874</NUMBER>
    <DESCRIPTION>SOCKS</DESCRIPTION>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
    <NUMBER>64971</NUMBER>
    <DESCRIPTION>JIGSAW</DESCRIPTION>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
    <NUMBER>25597</NUMBER>
    <DESCRIPTION>FUEL CANISTER</DESCRIPTION>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
    <NUMBER>31648</NUMBER>
  </ORDER>
</ORDERSINFO>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/ORDERSINFO/ORDER[DESCRIPTION][last()]
```

will select the last `ORDER` element that has a `DESCRIPTION`,

```
<ORDER>
  <NUMBER>25597</NUMBER>
  <DESCRIPTION>FUEL CANISTER</DESCRIPTION>
</ORDER>
```

as requested.

---

If you wish to select the last `DESCRIPTION` that has content which is not empty or whitespace, use this XPath instead:

```
/ORDERSINFO/ORDER[DESCRIPTION[normalize-space()]][last()]
```